# Can't Edit Table Because there's no Primary Key, Can't Create Key Because there are Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The title says it all really - there's a table in a MySql DB that I want to be able to edit - so I try to assign a primary key. Unfortunately, for some reason there is a duplicated record which means that I can't create a primary key - and in a bit of a catch 22 I can't change or delete the record so that I create the key because there isn't a key (ad infinatum).

Is there any simple way around this, short of either inserting a new field and populating it with unique data, creating the key and then changing the duplicate record and deleting the new field - or clearing the table?

Comment: You should be able to create a primary key called id or something and it will add it automatically to the database accordingly. I don't think it has anything to do with duplicated records

Comment: Have you tried editing the table from the Mysql command line. You should be able to edit without a PK but I know Mysql Workbench has a setting that prohibits that, maybe phpmyadmin has added that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your solution is the simplest here -- create a new column to use as a temporary primary key.

The reason for this is that phpMyAdmin requires a key for editing, because without one it can become quite difficult to make sure an edit isn't affecting the wrong row. Anyway, I suggest doing exactly as you proposed so that you can edit within phpMyAdmin and then move the primary key over to the proper column.

**EDIT**:
By the way, phpMyAdmin has added some support (beginning with version 4.5.0) for editing without a primary key existing, but the table needs to have enough unique information in place for this to work and isn't guaranteed to be available for every structure, so the best way (both in terms of using phpMyAdmin and general MySQL data integrity) are to have a primary key.

Comment: you saved my Saturday, thanks for this simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

Set in you config.inc.php

```
$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] = true;
```

But Remember its not save to use.

Comment: This line was not there but I added it and it is working like a charm!